# Getting selected items in a listview into sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I have i custom  checklist of student details and i want to get the details of selected item into SQlite database. the custom Listview contains the student "reg_no" , "firstname", "Lastname" and "surname". Any quick help is highly appreciated. Here is my code.

MainActvity.java

```
public class StudentTake100Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lvStudentlist;
    private StudentListAdapter1 adapter;
    private List<StudentList> mStudentList;
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_take100);

        lvStudentlist= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_studentlist);
        lvStudentlist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        mStudentList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Add sample data for list
        //We can get data from DB, webservice here
        mStudentList.add(new StudentList(1, "U11EE1001", "Bargo","S.","Mayafi"));
        mStudentList.add(new StudentList(2, "U11EE1002", "Barnsbas","Snake.","Maciji"));
        mStudentList.add(new StudentList(3, "U11EE1004", "Adamu","Tanko.","Sadau"));
        mStudentList.add(new StudentList(4, "U11EE1005", "Munzali","","Cire Tallafi"));


        //Init adapter
        adapter = new StudentListAdapter1(getApplicationContext(), mStudentList);
        lvStudentlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        lvStudentlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Do something
                SparseBooleanArray checked = lvStudentlist.getCheckedItemPositions();

                int size = checked.size(); // number of name-value pairs in the array
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    int key = checked.keyAt(i);
                    boolean value = checked.get(key);
                    if (value)
                        doSomethingWithSelectedIndex(key);
                    db.addAttendanceList(key);
                }


            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: bad practice to ask the same question on the next thread after modifying it, you can edit the question here itself.

Comment: Your answer is wrong and i got down vote for the question. I didn't know that i can edit the question, am not i use to asking question here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your onItemClickListener to the below implementation:

```
lvStudentlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

StudentList studentList = (StudentList)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //Do something
        //SparseBooleanArray checked = //lvStudentlist.getCheckedItemPositions();

        //int size = checked.size(); // number of name-value pairs in the array
        //for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            //int key = checked.keyAt(i);
            //boolean value = checked.get(key);
            //if (value)
               // doSomethingWithSelectedIndex(key);
            //db.addAttendanceList(key);
        //}

// get items from the studentList object

String studentName = studentList.getName();
int regNo = studentList.getRegNo(); // other fields as well


    }
});
```

work with these fields as you want, i hope u have getters in your StudentList class. This should do it.

Comment: Thank you. please checkout this question is more precise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837568/getting-selected-items-in-a-listview-into-sqlite-database.

Comment: Thank you,but i want to get only the checked details. please checkout this question is more precise and has picture of my work@vibhor_shri.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841727/getting-selected-items-details-in-a-listview-into-sqlite-database